# Is there any way to comment cron job using ansible

Tags: ansible, cron

I tried using the below code-

```
 - name: "cron"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - cron:
        name: "Puppet agent"
        job: "/bin/true"
        state: present
        disabled: True
```

instead of commenting the existing cron job, it appended with #Ansible: test. I would like to modify the existing cron job, not to append.

The cron job looks like this-
crontab -l

```
# puppet Name: Puppet agent
* * * * * /bin/true
```

the result after executing the ansible code is:
crontab -l

```
# puppet Name: Puppet agent
 * * * * * /bin/true
# Ansible: Puppet agent
#* * * * * /bin/true
```

Comment: Well, ansible expected that a previous playbook had used the `cron:` task to insert that entry, and thus did not recognize the parts of a hand-modified crontab. You'll want to use one of the `...infile:` tasks to bring that crontab into compliance in order to begin managing it with ansible

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Can you please explain more on the infile: task. How can i use it?

Comment: see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html (there's the lineinfile, and the blockinfile module)

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments, I found that if cron is maintained by ansible then we can modify cron job using my earlier approach otherwise ...infile: is the best option. My requirement was to comment multiple lines from the cron job. So,my code looks as below-

```
lineinfile:
      path: /var/spool/cron/root
      # Line to Search/Match against
      regexp: '{{item.From}}'
      # Line to Replace with
      line: '{{item.To}}'
      state: present  
    with_items:
     - { From: '/bin/true', To: '#* * * * * /bin/true'}
     - { From: '/bin/test.sh', To: '#* * * * * /bin/test.sh'}
```

I hope this would help others.